# OAuth 2.0 Authorization flow using Keycloak without redirect to KeyCloak Login UI

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, keycloak

We are designing an OAuth 2.0 authorization flow. In this flow, when login details are sent to keycloak, it redirects to the UI of keycloak User Login.

Is it possible to completly avoid the redirect and going to the Keycloak login page? Instead keycloak would directly accept the user credentials via the api and returns the authorization code directly, without the Keycloak login page.

Is this something that is possible and it is appropriate as per Oauth 2.0?
We are only interested in the authorization flow, not any other Oauth flow

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible because it wouldn't be secure. With your approach any developer with access to your code, today or in few years, could write user’s credentials to the log file. With the Keycloak login page it is not possible. You can however customize the Keycloak login page with your own design.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Its just that we will need to expose Keycloak publicly and having to expose the authentication server publicly could be a bit of risk

Comment: The risk is much bigger if you expose something you created. The Keycloak is created and reviewed according to the best security practices and standards and regularly patched. It is hard to keep up with that.